# Modern Hebrew Morphology Reference Book

Tags: resource-request, hebrew

I am currently learning Modern Hebrew, but I am still a complete novice.

I reckon morphological analysis to be a beneficial exercise, yet the lack of resources where I could check my assumptions up hinders the process.

Can anyone, please recommend any materials of such sort?

In order to make this question a small bit clearer, I should probably note that I am requesting a more "prescriptive" resource rather than a "descriptive" one. I.e. something that works for Hebrew just like D. E. Rosenthal's texts work for the Russian language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best Modern Hebrew morphology reference that I've found is Lewis Glinert's [Modern Hebrew: An Essential Grammar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XDQJZYH) (no relationship).

In this book, Glinert mentions that he is, in fact, concentrating on usage rather than prescription, but goes into detail as to how the presence of specific root letters (e.g. א, ע, ח, etc.) affect the final pronunciations when they are plugged in to the various noun and verb templates. There is some discussion of the linguistic reasons (mostly phonological attributes of the sounds themselves or of their pre-modern versions) but it is not as in-depth as one might hope. I found this very refreshing compared to the heavily memorization-based focus (here's another verb, memorize it) of so many other Modern Hebrew learning materials.